# Add user input to pre-populated combobox?

Tags: c#, xaml, revit-api

I have a combo box that is prepopulated with several numbers that represent the percentage of masonry on the exterior veneer of a house. These numbers are some of the typical coverages, but I also want the user to be able to input a number in case the plan they're working on is not typical. I checked the box for IsEditable, so I'm able to input my own number, but every time I do that Revit throws and error saying that "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object."

this is where, in the code-behind I am populating the combobox:

```
List<string> listMasonry = new List<string> { "0", "25", "50", "75", "100" };

            foreach (string masonry in listMasonry)
            {
                cmbCodeMasonry.Items.Add(masonry);
            }

            cmbCodeMasonry.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

and here is where in the code-behind I'm getting the error:

```
 public string GetComboBoxCodeMasonrySelectedItem()
        {
            return cmbCodeMasonry.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

and here is my XAML code:

`<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCodeMasonry" Grid.Column="1" Width="90" Height="25" Grid.Row="4" IsEditable="True"/>`

What am I missing?

I'm expecting the masonry code on titlblocks to update to the user input number.

Comment: You're creating a ComboBox with a set of five items. Those are the only objects in the ComboBox. If you let the user type in a different value, there is no item that matches and thus SelectedItem is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not letting me comment on my own question. I understand what's happening, but not why. According to research I've done on the internet, setting the value of IsEditable to true, should allow for both pre-populated choices AND for user input.

Is this not correct? Is it possible to have both, or is it only one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what you want:
`return cmbCodeMasonry.Text;`